# XQuery: Compare xml node value with a value stored in disk file

Tags: xml, xquery, soapui

I am looking for a method via which we can compare an xml node value with a node value stored in a disk file. In short, how to read the xml file in `xquery`?

I am using `SoapUI` for testing a `RESTful` service where I want to check the contents of a response with the contents of a file stored on disk.

Is such thing possible in `xquery`?

I have tried the following example:

```
//customer/id=doc("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Testing related\\cust.xml")/customer/id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`deep-equal($node1, $node2)`](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_deep-equal.html) for **comparing whole subtrees**.

```
deep-equal(//customer/id, doc("cust.xml")/customer/id)
```

If there are multiple customer ids, you will have to loop over them yourself; `deep-equal` does not have the same "set semantics" like `=` has.

**Opening documents with `doc(...)`** is somewhat implementation dependent. SOAPUI uses Saxon to evaluate XPath and XQuery, so read their [documentation on the `doc(...)` function](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!functions/fn/doc) to realize they want the URI of the element, like you could pass one to Java's `URIResolver` class.

```
doc("file:///C:/Documents and Settings/Testing related/cust.xml")
```

Comment: OK. I got the point about the equating two nodes but my actual question is about `how to read the disk file into xquery`? Can you share some pointers on that?

Comment: I got it! I used `deep-equal(//customer/id, doc("file:///C:/Documents and Settings/testing/cust.xml")/customer/id)` and it compared just as I expected! But yours and @Ewout combined answer solved this issue. Which one should I accept as answer? :P

Comment: Didn't realize there was something wrong with it as `doc(...)` is implementation dependent and you didn't mention what's the actual problem you have. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a file uri: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme but I'm not 100% sure if this is something implementation dependent. At least the following works in xDB:

```
doc("file:///c:/path/to/file.xml")
```

Comment: Thank you for useful info! It helped partially :) +1